# Why can't I Union two JArray?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my code:

```
JArray first;
JArray second;
JArray test = first.Union(second);
```

but it says that it cannot do an implicit conversion between JToken and in JArray?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because union produces enumerable result of distinct values from both enumerable sources. Thus first and second are `IEnumerable<JToken>` then your correct result type will be `IEnumerable<JToken>`:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> test = first.Union(second);
```

Creating JArray is simple - it has constructor which allows to pass enumerable content:

```
JArray array = new JArray(first.Union(second));
```

Comment: good catch, people write `var test = first.Union(second);` and forget that it returns `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: And how can I convert `IEnumerable<JToken>` into `JArray`? I don't see any `.ToJArray`